# SQL Server Password

Tags: sql-server-2005, passwords

Is there any way of retreaving a SQL Server Authenticatiion password. I am running Server 2005 with admin rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tool to retrieve it:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vbscript/SQLServerPasswords.aspx

More information:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic664614-391-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the database in single user mode. Here is an article going through the steps:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160305201328/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/raulga/archive/2007/07/12/disaster-recovery-what-to-do-when-the-sa-account-password-is-lost-in-sql-server-2005.aspx)